# How to change the name of input types dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I am adding a row on button click in a form/table.

SO I am just copying the content of the last row and adding it to the new row. Since it is a form I will have to change the name of the input types so that I could use it to save in a database .

My code looks something like this

```
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>One</option>
                <option>Two</option>
            </select>
            <button class="makeStrng">+</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="addRow">Add ME</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".addRow,.makeStrng", function () {
        var $class = $(this).attr("class");
        if ($class == "addRow") {
            var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); // Finds the closest row <tr>
            var prev = $row.prev();
            $(prev).after("<tr>" + prev.html() + "</tr>");
        }

});
```

The js fiddle for this is

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/qsq2dhen/5/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make them the types of the inputs as arrays. It should be

```
<select name="opt[]">
<input type="text" name="inp[]" />
```

In this way when you duplicate the row you do not have to do anything. In the controller you can do a for in each array and get the data.

Comment: Kool! bro yeah How can I not think about this :D . Can you just give me some Idea what should I do in the controller . Like I am using PHP so what would be the snippet thanks anyways for this

Comment: I got it bro no need to write . I will accept your answer in two minutes :D

Comment: :) happy to be of help